# How to detect some pattern with grep -f on a file in terminal, and extract those lines without the pattern

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I'm on mac terminal.
I have a txt file with one column with 9 IDs, allofthem.txt, where every ID starts with ¨rs¨:

```
rs382216
rs11168036
rs9296559
rs9349407
rs10948363
rs9271192
rs11771145
rs11767557
rs11
```

Also, I have another txt file, useful.txt, with those IDs that were useful in an analysis I did. It looks the same, one column with several rows of IDs, but with less IDS, only 5.

```
rs9349407
rs10948363
rs9271192
rs11
```

Problem:I want to generate a new txt file with the non-useful ones (the ones that appear in allofthem.txt but not in useful.txt).

I want to do the inverse of:

```
grep -f useful.txt allofthem.txt
```

I want to use some systematic way of deleting all the IDs in useful and obtain a file with the remaining ones. Maybe with awk or sed, but I can´t see it. Can you help me, please? Thanks in advance!

Desired output:

```
rs382216
rs11168036
rs9296559
rs11771145
rs11767557
```

Comment: I wanted to know the command, and as the other person answered, it was -vf. I didn´t know that you could merge the both (I knew -v and -f, but didn´t know that you could use -vf at the same time). Now it works :) . I wanted to understand the concept and get to know the command, not to have an exact result regarding my real IDs. (look at the answer).

Comment: I'm sorry @Ed Morton , I don't know what the problem is... the answer provided below was exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: I only needed that to extract the 14 IDs that were "not useful", and it did... In my computer they're not random. If you want, I edit the question to leave some similar, invented example...

Comment: I edited it. That's ok?I want to clarify that what I wanted was to know the appropriate command, which was -vf, so my problem is fixed.

Comment: @EdMorton - the `-x` option in `grep` would address that issue, isn't it?  Look at my updated answer.

Comment: This is a place where there is people beginning to learn, and there are others that are experts. Don't get frustrated if people need to discuss things.  Forums are for that. Also, if you would have explain the complete issue clearly in your first comment as you did in one of your later comments, I could have understood and edited sooner. I didn't understand you at first. It happens to all of us, even to you, as you can see...

Comment: @melunge92 I asked you to post concise, testable sample input and expected output and referred you to the guidelines on [ask]. My only frustration is due to you not just doing that, nothing to do with misunderstandings or the need to discuss anything. There are several possible issues with your initial question but immediately getting into a discussion on issues you may not have is pointless, hence my request to simply see representative data per the SO quidelines for asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

`-v` option does the inverse for you:

```
grep -vxf useful.txt allofthem.txt > remaining.txt
```

`-x` option matches the whole line in allofthem.txt, not parts.

As @hek2mgl rightly pointed out, you need `-F` if you want to treat the content of useful.txt as strings and not patterns:

```
grep -vxFf useful.txt allofthem.txt > remaining.txt
```

Make sure your files have no leading or trailing white spaces - they could affect the results.

Comment: I didn´t know that you could merge the syntax like that ! I knew -v and -f but didn´t know that you could do -vf. That does exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Ahhh, ok! thanks for clarifying ! Now I get why the answer wasn't entirely right.

Comment: The `-x` option does address that issue.

Comment: @codeforester I'm sorry. I overlooked that. And I need to admit that I was not aware that `-x` exists. Thanks for that!

Comment: @melunuge92 - any reason why you unaccepted the answer?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend to use `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{patterns[$0];next} $0 in patterns' useful.txt allofthem.txt
```

Explanation:

`FNR==NR` is true as long as we are reading `useful.txt`. We create an index in `patterns` for every line of `useful.txt`. `next` stops further processing.

`$0 in patterns` runs, because of the previous `next` statement, on every line of `allofthem.txt`. It checks for every line of that file if it is a key in `patterns`. If that checks evaluates to `true` `awk` will print that line.

Comment: It's getting better but you didn't include the single most important case of `rs11` (or some other id that's part of other ids) in useful.txt. With what you have now you could get a solution (e.g. `grep -vf`) that falsely excludes all of the IDs from allofthem.txt that start with `rs11` in that situation and you'd walk away thinking you had a solution to your problem (as you almost did) because the test for that wasn't part of your sample input/output and it'd fail cryptically and silently 6 months later when run on real data.

Comment: This has the effect of `grep -xFf`, not `grep -vxFf`.

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry, I overlooked your comment. I think `$0 in patterns` checks the whole string `$0`, right?

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes it does. My comment was just a reply to the OPs comment though.